# Ansible : how to rename a file when copying it

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a task , where should I **copy** a file from its source , to its destination **while renaming it in the destination** .

My task looks like this :

```
- name: Go to the target folder
  shell: ls
  args:
   chdir: "{{pathTest}}/target"
  register: resultLS
- debug:
   msg: "{{resultLS}}"
- name: copy jar file
  copy:
   src: "{{resultLS.stdout}}"
   dest: "{{pathTest}}"
   mode: 0777
```

But, like this it copies the jar file with its same name , **my purpose is how to rename it in the `dest` (ideally with the copy action)**

**Ideas ?**

Comment: Rename to what?

Comment: @techraf :  rename it to : renamed.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rename it to: `renamed.jar`

Here you are:

```
- name: Ensure the first matched file from {{ pathTest }}/target is present on the target
  copy:
    src: "{{ lookup('fileglob', pathTest + '/target/*') | first }}"
    dest: "{{ pathTest }}/renamed.jar"
    mode: 0777
```

Remarks:

- [Don't parse `ls` output!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/133107)
- Think how you should handle multiple files.

  <sup>*in the example above - copy only the first one*</sup>